# Sum list up until element changes, then start again

Tags: python, list, sum

Is there some way iterating over a list and summing a column once there is a chnage in the name of one element.

```
[['a','1'],['a','2'],['a','3']....on and on, ['b','1'],['b','2'],['b','3']...
on and on....]]
```

So while there's 'a's at [0], sum the index 1 column, then if [0] changes (ie. 'b'), then start summing again. So I guess it could be a sort of while loop but just can't figure it out. I was thinking along the lines of (but is obviously wrong)...

```
    for row in list:
        for i in row:  #iterate through each row
            var = i[0] #assign first index to 'var'
            while True: #while var is one name
                for num in lst:
                    sum(float(num[1]) for num in lst if num[1])   #add column [1]
            ....then something else...
```

A few things- I don't want to specify the elements name ('a','b'..) because it will change.
The number of element types may also change- sometimes just 'a','b' and sometimes 'c', 'd','e', etc
And I need to somehow store the summed values each time the first element changes

Is this possible without using dict or modules, etc?

Comment: What's wrong with dictionaries?

Comment: You mention you don't want to use `dict`... do you mean you don't want to store as a `dict`, or don't want use to use a `dict` in your solution?  I ask because using a `dict` in the solution might make it easier.

Comment: Not using dict or modules makes it seem like a homework problem. If that's the case you should mention that

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your items:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sums = [(key, sum(float(i[1]) for i in group))
        for key, group in groupby(row, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

This produces a list of `('a', 10.0)`, etc. values.

The `groupby()` tool splits up your input sequence into groups, where the next group is determined by the `key` callable; when the value returned by the `key` callable changes, a new group is produced.

Comment: so the 0 referred to in key=itemgetter(0) is actually the index number of the item that changes??

Comment: @Op.Ivy: Yes, `itemgetter(0)` returns the item at index `0` for each value in your list. So `row[0][0]` is `a`, `row[1][0]` is also `a`, so that's the same group, etc. until you get to `row[n][0]` and it's `b`, so that's a new group.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for `itertools.groupby()`, which allows you to group elements from one iterable.  It might look something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
data = [['a','1'],['a','2'],['a','3'], ['b','1'],['b','2'],['b','3'],['b','4']]
sums = [(k, sum(float(v) for k, v in g)) for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Result:

```
>>> sums
[('a', 6.0), ('b', 10.0)]
```

Comment: It'd be worth noting that if the values are always integers, as in the OP's question, `int()` might be preferable to `float()`. Also, if the data is not sorted to begin with (although it appears to be in the example), it will need to be.

Comment: Agreed, I only used `float()` to be consistent with the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you are adding things, you can use a Counter

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [['a', '1'], ['a', '2'], ['a', '3'], ['b', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['b', '3']]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for i,j in L:
...  c.update({i: float(j)})
... 
>>> c
Counter({'a': 6.0, 'b': 6.0})
```

Comment: What if the `a` key comes back again later on and the OP wants that group to be summed separately? From the question I infer that only consecutive keys should be summed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, then it might not be what the OP wants. Depends whether keys can come up again I guess.

Comment: They will always be consecutive